# Get the UTF-8 Encoding of a Character in Bytes

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, character-encoding, character

On a `String`, I can use `utf8` and `count` to get the number of bytes required to encode the String with UTF-8 encoding:

```
"a".utf8.count // 1
"チャオ".utf8.count // 9
"チ".utf8.count // 3
```

However, I don't see an equivalent method on a single `Character` value.  To get the number of bytes required to encode a character in the string to UTF-8, I could iterate through the string by character, convert the Character to a String, and get the `utf8.count` of that String:

```
"チャオ".characters.forEach({print(String($0).utf8.count)}) // 3, 3, 3
```

This seems unnecessarily verbose.  Is there a way to get the UTF-8 encoding of a `Character` in Swift?

Comment: Why `underestimateCount`? `let c = "チャオ".utf8.count` gives the exact UTF-8 length of a string.

Comment: @MartinR good point, I'll use `count` instead.  But what about getting the size on a character-by-character basis?

Comment: As far as I know, conversion to a String is the only way.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Character` has no direct (public) accessor to its UTF-8 representation.

There are some internal methods in [Character.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Character.swift) dealing with the UTF-8 bytes, but the public stuff is implemented in
`String.UTF8View` in [StringUTF8.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8.swift).

Therefore `String(myChar).utf8.count` is the correct way to obtain
the length of the characters UTF-8 representation.